How to reduce the margin between two buttons in below WPF code
I tried all the ways to reduce space between two buttons named Analyze and ShowMap. But I am getting as the above attached image. Code is as below
 <Grid>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
         <RowDefinition Height="*" />
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <Label Content="Plot File" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10" />
     <TextBox x:Name="txtMultiBox" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,0,10,10" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
     <Button Style="{StaticResource Highlight}"   Content="Browse" x:Name="btnBrowse" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10" Click="btnBrowse_Click" />
     <Button Style="{StaticResource Highlight}"  Content="Analyze" x:Name="btnAnalyze" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="left" Margin="10,10,5,7.5" Click="btnAnalyze_Click" />
     <Button Style="{StaticResource Highlight}" Visibility="Hidden"  Content="ShowMap" x:Name="btnShowmap" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="left" Margin="5,10,10,10"  Click="btnShowmap_Click" />
     <Label Content="Parcels" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,7.5,10,0" />
     <TreeView SelectedItemChanged="tvSections_SelectedItemChanged"  x:Name="tvSections" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Margin="10,0,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
     <Label Content="Assosiated Sections" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,7.5,10,0" />
     <ListView x:Name="lsParcels" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="4" Margin="10,0,10,10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
         <ListView.View>
             <GridView>
                 <GridViewColumn Header="FID"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Fid}"/>
                 <GridViewColumn Header="ParcelId"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ParcelId}"/>
             </GridView>
         </ListView.View>
     </ListView>
 </Grid>


Your code says they're in different columns ("Analyze" is in Grid.Column="1" and "ShowMap" is in Grid.Column="2") so you're at the mercy of the grid at-large. Your columns are defined with Width="*" which means they'll take up equal space. You could swap column 1 to Width="auto" to only take up the necessary space (leaving column 0 and column 2 as Width="*" to share the remaining space).

One possible solution would be to wrap the two button in StackPanel with Orientation="Horizontal", occupying the same place in the Grid as the buttons:
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Style="{StaticResource Highlight}"  Content="Analyze" x:Name="btnAnalyze" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="left" Margin="10,10,5,7.5" Click="btnAnalyze_Click" />
    <Button Style="{StaticResource Highlight}" Visibility="Hidden"  Content="ShowMap" x:Name="btnShowmap" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="left" Margin="5,10,10,10"  Click="btnShowmap_Click" />
</StackPanel>


Thanks it worked.Width="auto" also will work
